# monero-wallet-cli mining

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cpu-mining

After running `monerod` I started mining with the command `start_mining (my wallet adress) 1`.
After a while I ran the command `mining_status`.

The result was this:

```
mining_status
Mining at 101 H/s with 1 threads
PoW algorithm: RandomX
Mining address: 44AQ4...sFrn
Expected: 0.000045739943 monero daily, 0.001395068269 monero monthly, 0.016283419795 yearly
```

My question is this, how will I be able to see how many Monero I've already made and when will I receive it in my wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Mining directly in the wallet or daemon you don't earn anything until you actually mine a block. With your exceptionally low hashrate (101 H/s), that would be sometime in the next ~75 years.

Comment: Leaving aside that 100H/s is a very slow speed, why 75 years if monero blocks are of different sizes? there are large and small blocks, the estimation in years should be done in a time range based on the minimum and maximum block size

Comment: The _size_ of a block has no bearing on ones luck to mine a block. Only your hashrate vs network hashrate and the block difficulty target.